# No data insertion when button pressed

Tags: php, mysql

When i press the submit button to insert record, it pulls out no error but when i check the database i find no records submitted too. please what could be wrong with my script. just started with php

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['submitted'])){

        include('Connections/connect.php');

        $term= $_POST['term'];
        $details= $_POST['details'];



$sql = "INSERT INTO people (term,details) VALUES ($term,$details)";



$newrecord ="Inserted Successfully";

    }

?>
```

connect.php

```
<?php

$hostname_speedapp = "localhost";
$database_speedapp = "mydb";
$username_speedapp = "root";
$password_speedapp = "password";
$mydb= mysqli_connect($hostname_mydb, $username_mydb, $password_mydb) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>
```

HTML

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="page1.php">
  <p>
    <label for="term"></label>
    <input type="text" name="term" id="term" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label for="details"></label>
    <input type="text" name="details" id="details" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
     <input name="submitted" type="hidden" value="submitted"  />
  </p>
</form>
<p>
<?php
$newrecord
?>
```

Comment: where is your insert to the database

Comment: You're just defining the query string, not actually executing the query anywhere. Check out the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) for info on the `MySQLi` extension. Also, your query is open to SQL injection, so you should read [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: there are so many errors in this question, it's not funny. Plus, a few things that nobody even caught. *Facepalm*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO people (term,details) VALUES ($term,$details)";

    if (mysqli_query($mydb, $sql))
    {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } 
    else
    {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($mydb);
    }
```

**EDIT 01**

```
$hostname_speedapp = "localhost";
$database_speedapp = "mydb";
$username_speedapp = "root";
$password_speedapp = "password";
$mydb= mysqli_connect($hostname_mydb, $username_mydb, $password_mydb) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
```

and top of `page1.php`

```
include("connect.php");
```

Comment: @i_user check your missing lines

Comment: @i_user check edit 1. and check database name is correct

Comment: @i_user happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot wrong with your code
Let's take it step by step:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['submitted'])){

        include('Connections/connect.php');

        $term= $_POST['term'];
        $details= $_POST['details'];
```

You are not escaping here. When I'm a bad man I could destroy your application
Read more about escaping here: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO people (term,details) VALUES ($term,$details)";
```

You are defining a query here but you do not do anything with this query
read about executing query's on the php documentation page: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

```
$newrecord ="Inserted Successfully";
```

You are defining a variable `$newrecord` here but it does not have a function here. Add `echo $newrecord;` to echo the value of the variable `$newrecord`: http://php.net/echo

```
    }

?>
```

Then you are not using the correct variables in your `connect.php`

```
<?php

$hostname_speedapp = "localhost";
$database_speedapp = "mydb";
$username_speedapp = "root";
$password_speedapp = "password";
$mydb= mysqli_connect($hostname_mydb, $username_mydb, $password_mydb) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>
```

You are defining `$hostname_speedapp` and using `$hostname_mydb` in your `mysqli_connect` change that to `$hostname_speedapp` etc.. changing your connection string to:
`$mydb= mysqli_connect($hostname_speedapp, $username_speedapp, $password_speedapp)`

You are not selecting a database in your connectionstring. You are defining a variable with your database name called: `$database_speedapp` but you never use it.

Change your connectionstring to: `$mydb= mysqli_connect($hostname_speedapp, $username_speedapp, $password_speedapp, $database_speedapp)` and you should be good to go

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
 ` $sql = "INSERT INTO people (term,details) VALUES ($term,$details)";
   $result=mysqli_query($mydb,$sql);`
```

Comment: it gives me this error: Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given

Answer (score 0):

You dont even have an insert query in your script.

```
$hostname_speedapp = "localhost";
$database_speedapp = "mydb";
$username_speedapp = "root";
$password_speedapp = "password";
$mydb= mysqli_connect($hostname_mydb, $username_mydb, $password_mydb) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

$sql = "INSERT INTO people (term,details) VALUES ($term,$details)";

if (mysqli_query($mydb, $sql)) {
    $newrecord ="Inserted Successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($mydb);
}

mysqli_close($mydb);
```

Comment: @i_user make sure you have a database selected and both the connection script and insert query script are in the same page

Answer (score 0):

Connect.php

```
  <?php
  $hostname_speedapp = "localhost";
  $database_speedapp = "mydb";
  $username_speedapp = "root";
  $password_speedapp = "password";
  $mydb= mysqli_connect($hostname_speedapp, $username_speedapp, $password_speedapp,$database_speedapp) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR); 
?>
```

page1.php

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

    include('Connections/connect.php');

    $term= $_POST['term'];
    $details= $_POST['details'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO people (term,details) VALUES ('".$term."' , '".$details."')";
    if ($mydb->query($sql) === TRUE) {     //can use connected database $mydb 
             $newrecord = "New record created successfully";
    } else {
       echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $mydb->error;
    }

  }
 ?>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
<p>
<label for="term"></label>
<input type="text" name="term" id="term" />
</p>
<p>
<label for="details"></label>
<input type="text" name="details" id="details" />
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
</p>
</form>
<p>
<?php
if(isset($newrecord)){
echo "<h3>$newrecord</h3>";
}
?>
```

Comment: nothing will fire up (will throw a notice). Plus, think about what will happen if someone enters nothing in the inputs ;-) not to mention about still leaving them open to SQL injection.

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to quote the submitted data values in your sql query:

Change the following:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO people (term,details) VALUES ($term,$details)";
```

to

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO people (term,details) VALUES ('$term','$details')";
```

Comment: you're the only one who got this. No idea why it was so heavily downvoted. I gave you an upvote. You did miss a few things, but that shouldn't be a reason why your answer received so many downvotes and with no reason. Nobody else caught that, and I don't know why they even got upvotes for not getting everything and clearly missed some also.

Comment: I did miss the fact the OP hadn't included the actual sql execute but wondered why so many downvotes - thanks for the upvote @Fred-ii- :)

Comment: watch the others start to change their answers lol - give it time ;-) I for one, will not be submitting an answer. There are far too many things wrong with that question, it's really not funny.